How to instantiate recursive type with heap pointers?
Consider the following structs:
struct Foo {
    val: i32,
    bar: Box<Bar>,
}

struct Bar {
    val: i32,
    foo: Box<Foo>,
}

I tried to instantiate it as:
let foo = Box::new(Foo {
    val: 10,
    bar: Box::new(Bar { val: 20, foo }),
});

But got compile time error:
cannot find value `foo` in this scope

Is there a way to instantiate such type?

It's obviously not possible with plain Box es because only one owner is allowed for a type at a time and it can't be both foo and foo.bar.foo.
